# How can I get or make gems above the "Star" level?

Tags: diablo-iii

I maxed out my jeweler (level 10) and "Star" jewels are the best he can make, though the Auction House shows listings for Flawless, Perfect, and Radiant Star gems (higher levels than "Star"). Are these gems dropped in Inferno or somewhere else? If not, how can I make them? Do "plans" exist for these gem levels somewhere? If so, where can I find them?

[image: Auction House listing] [image: Star gems]

Comment: Something that isn't mentioned yet in the answers is how to make your jeweler aware of the plans you have. To do that make sure you are carrying your plans, go to Covetous Shen, open the gem combiner, then right click on the plans that you are carrying. New options will then become available in the combiner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The highest level gem plans are dropped items.  You can see all the jeweler recipies [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/).

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any specific place that has a higher chance of dropping them than anywhere else, so the standard diablo answer of "go to a level appropriate area, and kill things".

Answer (score 11):

They are plans. From the [Battle.net](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/) site you can see each gem and what it takes. You will see in the bottom of the picture that it says you get it from a Design. I suspect that since it takes tombs of secrets to create that it only drops in Inferno.[image]